# Implement pull to refresh FlatList in React native

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-native-flatlist

**Flatlist code**

```
class HomeScreen extends Component {
      state = { refreshing: false }
    
      _renderItem = ({ item }) => <ImageGrid item={item} />
    
      _handleRefresh = () => {
    
      };
    
      render() {
        const { data } = this.props;
        if (data.loading) {
          return (
            <Root>
              <Loading size="large" />
            </Root>
          )
        }
```

//render
return (


<FlatList
contentContainerStyle={{ alignSelf: 'stretch' }}
data={data.getPosts}
keyExtractor={item => item._id}
renderItem={this._renderItem}
numColumns={3}
refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
onRefresh={this._handleRefresh}
/>

);
}
}

> implemented with class component

Answer (score 0):

Make changes:

```
_handelRefresh=async()=>{
            this.setState({refreshing: true})
            this.YOURAPIFunction();
            this.setState({refreshing: false})
        } 
       
    <FlatList 
           contentContainerStyle={{ alignSelf: 'stretch' }} 
           data={data.getPosts} 
           keyExtractor={item => item._id} 
           renderItem={this._renderItem} 
           numColumns={3} 
           refreshing={this.state.refreshing} 
           onRefresh={this._handleRefresh} 
         />
```